# Copy and paste multiple cells within DataGridView

Tags: datagridview

I've seen that the Datagridview doesn't enable one to copy and paste the text of more than one cells, is there a simple setting to enable that or do I have to use the key handler and clipboard data store to include that functionality.

A user wants to copy 3 cells within a row and be able to paste the text of them in a different row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I got a solution but it hasn't been tested by pasting cells accross multiple rows.This is the KeyDown event of the datagridview

```
 if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
            {
                DataObject d = AccountGrid.GetClipboardContent();
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(d);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
            {
                string s = Clipboard.GetText();
                string[] lines = s.Split('\n');
                int row = AccountGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                int col = AccountGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                string[] cells = lines[0].Split('\t');
                int cellsSelected = cells.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < cellsSelected; i++)
                {
                    AccountGrid[col, row].Value = cells[i];
                    col++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: if multiple datagridviews then??

Answer (score 1):

```
        string s = Clipboard.GetText();
        string[] lines = s.Split('\n');
        int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] cells = line.Split('\t');
            int cellsSelected = cells.Length;
            if (row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < cellsSelected; i++)
                {
                    if (col + i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count)
                        dataGridView1[col + i, row].Value = cells[i];
                    else
                        break;
                }
                row++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
{

string CopiedContent = Clipboard.GetText();
string[] Lines = CopiedContent.Split('\n');
int StartingRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
int StartingColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
foreach (var line in Lines)
{
    if (StartingRow <= (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1))
    {
       string[] cells = line.Split('\t');
       int ColumnIndex = StartingColumn;
       for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length && ColumnIndex <= (dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1); i++)
       {
          dataGridView1[ColumnIndex++, StartingRow].Value = cells[i];
       }
       StartingRow++;
   }
}}
```

Comment: This mostly works except for one situation. Let's say user selects 3 source cells with "T", "empty", "T". Copying these cells gives "T\r\n\r\nT". However, if I use the control key and select only the first and third cells (not selecting the second cell), I also get "T\r\n\r\nT". If the cells I am pasting to are not empty, I don't know if the blank in the middle cell should be pasted or not. In first use case, the user selected all three cells and would expect the middle blank to be pasted. In second use case, the user did NOT select the middle cell, so it shouldn't be pasted. How to know?